# How hard is gapped satisfiability?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, sat, promise-problems

It is well known that general satisfiability (of polynomially many clauses) is NP-hard, and in fact, it is conjectured that an algorithm deciding instances of SAT takes time nearly $2^n$ on $n$ variables.

I was wondering what, if anything, is known about the hardness of promise variants of the problem, GAP-SAT. Here the promise is that each such Boolean formula $\phi$ is guaranteed to lie in the union of

$$\Pi_{no} = \{\phi: |\{x:\phi(x) = 1 \}| \leq a\} $$ 
and
$$ \Pi_{yes} = \{\phi: |\{x:\phi(x) = 1 \}| \geq b\}$$

for different $0 \leq a = f(n) < b = g(n) \leq 2^n$ fixed functions of $n$. Any references would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Cross-posted from https://mathoverflow.net/q/295997

Comment: There is Gap Exponential Time Hypothesis which implies that there is no $2^{o(n)}$ algorithm for this problem for some $\varepsilon, \delta>0$ and $a=\varepsilon |\phi|, b=\delta |\phi|$. See https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2016/128/ and https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.02986 .